# Flask send_file as attachment the file download but ajax success function has no response

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, flask

I'm creating a YouTube Video Downloader for which I use flask for the backend. I send an ajax request to the flask in return a flask return file which by default set to download. The file starts downloading but the problem is that there is no responseText or statusCode in the success function in ajax
[Ajax Function](https://github.com/Haseeb1604/ajax.git) which I used to work in the same way as jquery ajax  does

My Ajax code is

```
    let formData = new FormData(downloadform);
    ajax({
      url: '/download',
      method: "POST",
      data: formData,
      onprogress: () => {
        download_loadingBtn.style.display = "block";
        downloadBtn.style.display = "none";
      },
      onsuccess: (responseText, status, statusText) => {
        download_loadingBtn.style.display = "none";
        downloadBtn.style.display = "block";
        console.log(responseText, status, statusText);
      },
      onfailure: (status, statusText) =>{
        console.log(status, statusText);
      }
    })
```

My Flask code  is

```
@app.route("/download", methods = ["GET", "POST"])
def download_video():
    if request.method == "POST":
        buffer = BytesIO()
        url = YouTube(session['link'])
        itag = request.form.get("itag")
        video = url.streams.get_by_itag(itag)
        video.stream_to_buffer(buffer)
        buffer.seek(0)
        return send_file(buffer, as_attachment=True, download_name=url.title, mimetype="video/mp4")
```

I also tried to return an object with some response text and send_file() such as

```
return jsonify({
       "text": "successfully downloaded",
       "download_file": send_file(buffer, as_attachment=True, download_name=url.title, mimetype="video/mp4") 
})
```

but that also gives an error i.e. TypeError: Object of type Response is not JSON serializable

Comment: Did you ever sort this out?

Comment: Nope, I just use its default behavior. I asked this issue to make an effect on download btn on the front end

Comment: Ok, thanks. I ended up making a GET request, since my form data was simple enough to encode as URL params.

Comment: how did you solve this?

Comment: still no answer